# Verliert das Verb "bergen" die Bedeutung "retten" - oder hat es das sogar bereits?

Tags: meaning

Immer wieder bemerke ich eine Dichtomisierung von "retten" im Sinne von "lebend aus einer (lebens-)gefährlichen Lage befreien" und "bergen" im Sinne von "einen Leichnam nach Verwirklichung der Gefahr bergen". (Man beachte, dass für den letzteren Sinn "bergen" tatsächlich das einzige Wort zu sein scheint! - Mir fallen zumindest keine weiteren ein...)

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bergen) verweist noch auf die primäre Bedeutung "retten, in  Sicherheit bringen", sogar ausdrücklich mit dem Beispiel "Verletzte bergen".

Insbesondere im Bereich der Notfallrettung und des Katastrophenschutzes scheint der vorherrschende Sprachgebrauch zu sein, zwischen retten und bergen strikt zu unterscheiden.

Bisher hatte ich in "tot", wie in der Wendung "eine Person konnte nur noch tot geborgen werden", immer eine zur Klarstellung notwendige Qualifikation gesehen: Die Person konnte eben nicht lebend, sondern nur mehr tot geborgen werden.

Zuletzt heute jedoch lese ich wieder ein **[Zitat von Sabine Lackner, der Vizepräsidentin des technischen Hilfswerks (THW)](https://www.badische-zeitung.de/thw-vizepraesidentin-wahrscheinlich-dass-man-opfer-nur-noch-bergen-kann-nicht-mehr-retten--203542400.html)**, die sagt, es sei sehr wahrscheinlich, dass man Opfer ([der aktuellen Hochwasserkatastrophe in Mitteleuropa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochwasser_in_West-_und_Mitteleuropa_2021)) **"nur noch bergen kann, nicht mehr retten."** - Die Trennung der Bedeutungen ist hier also offenbar vollständig: **"Bergen" schließt "retten" nicht (mehr) ein!**

Ist also die strikte Trennung zwischen lebend "retten" und tot "bergen" rein fachsprachlich - und sickert in die Alltagssprache ein? Oder ist das längst geschehen und ich bin in meiner veralteten Nutzung ein Relikt?

Antworten mit Belegen wären natürlich willkommen!

Comment: Anderseits ginge "Alle wurden sicher geborgen" genau so wie "... gerettet". In der Frage ist natürlich klar, was Frau Lackner meint. Möglicherweise ist der Bedeutungsunterschied vom Anwendungsfall abhängig ? Insofern wäre ich geneigt mit "nein" zu antworten ... nicht generell. Bin aber zu unsicher für eine Antwort.

Comment: Man sollte den Kontext mitnehmen - Jemanden aus einem vollkommen überfluteten Keller nach drei Tagen rauszuholen (zu bergen), läuft meistens nicht mehr auf "Rettung" hinaus. *Verwundete*, z.B. werden durchaus lebend geborgen und nicht "gerettet". "Bergen" impliziert eben hauptsächlich, dass der Geborgene nicht selber laufen kann - vielleicht, weil er sich das Bein gebrochen hat, vielleicht, weil er tot ist....

Comment: Die unmittelbare Folgerung aus dem Zitat ist aber eigentlich nicht, dass sich _bergen_ aus Sicht der Sprecherin nur auf Lebende bezieht, sondern dass sich _retten_ nicht auf Tote bezieht. Man kann die Menschen "nur noch *bergen*" - also: nicht auch zugleich *retten*. Deswegen scheint mir Ihr Schluss ("'Bergen' schließt 'retten' nicht (mehr) ein!") jedenfalls an dem Beispiel nicht recht einleuchtend.

Comment: @a_donda, ja, "alle wurden sicher geborgen" geht nach meinem Verständnis auch! - Die Quellenlage ist natürlich schwierig: Gerade die Verwendung in Nachrichten wird gerade von jenen dominiert, die offenbar diese Unterscheidung durchführen.

Comment: @johnl, danke für den Hinweis! Tatsächlich belegt das Zitat meinen Umkehrschluss nicht! - Ich werde versuchen, Belege für den wirklichen Ausschluss zu finden!

Comment: Für meine Begriffe ist "bergen" dann angebracht, wenn der (glückliche) Ausgang noch nicht sicher ist oder nicht eingetreten ist (z.B. "...nur noch tot geborgen..."). "Retten" impliziert, dass derjenige auch überlebt hat. Oder auch eine Sache: "Das Getreide konnte vor dem heranziehenden Unwetter ins Silo gerettet werden." "Bergen" ist also ein bisschen allgemeiner als "retten". Spannenderweise finde ich in einem Handbuch des THW folgenden Satz: "Bei der Rettung und Bergung von verletzten Personen ..." Das THW scheint also (für sich) die Begriffe zu unterscheiden. Für mich aber Fachsprache.

Answer (score 2):

"Bergen" heißt erst einmal nur "herausholen (oft: aus dem Problembereich)". Das mit "retten" gleichzusetzen ist genaugenommen falsch, aber ist im Grunde genommen Schritt 1 beim Ablauf einer Rettung. Von daher Auslegungssache, ob man beim Bergen schon von Rettung spricht oder erst, wenn die Rettung abgeschlossen ist, d.h. ob man den Prozess als solchen oder das Ergebnis so bezeichnet.

Answer (score 1):

**Nein**, hier in Österreich zumindest definitiv nicht.

Mit etwas Erklärung um das Wort herum, Gegenstände kann man nur bergen, man spricht kaum von Retten (außer vielleicht die Ernte vor dem Hagel, und andere seltene Anwendungsfälle)
Dadurch wird das Wort meistens für Wracks, Autos, Züge aber auch Leichen benutzt

Den Wortgebrauch den ich lokalen (Ö) Zeitungen entnehme wird bergen hauptsächlich verwendet wenn jemand feststeckt z.B. jemand fällt in eine [Gletscherspalte](https://www.kleinezeitung.at/kaernten/osttirol/aktuelles_osttirol/6016488/Praegraten-Matrei_Zwei-Personen-am-Grossvenediger-in), jemand steckt in einem [(Auto-)Wrack fest](https://www.kleinezeitung.at/kaernten/chronik/6012611/Maria-Elend_Pkw-ueberschlug-sich-mehrmals-Lenker-eingeklemmt)

Man tätigt hier Bergungsarbeiten um jemanden oder etwas zu befreien, mein Vater hat im Heer auch einen Bergepanzer gefahren, diese werden zum Retten verwendet sind aber dennoch *Berge*panzer

Übrigens nicht zu vergessen, wenn man [geborgen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geborgen) ist, ist man "sicher, gut aufgehoben" laut DWDS auch "entsprechend der Bedeutung von bergen"
Ebenso auch die Geborgenheit

Die [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bergen) "bergen" Beispiele helfen hier auch ganz gut denke ich:

> Hausrat, Wertsachen (bei einem Brand, einer Überschwemmung) bergen
>
> jmdn. (bei einem Unglück) lebend bergen (= retten)
>
> Schiffbrüchige, die Ladung eines gestrandeten Dampfers bergen
>
> die Rettungsmannschaft konnte vier Bergleute nur noch tot bergen (= vom Unglücksort
> wegbringen)
>
> die Ernte, das Heu bergen (= einbringen)

Answer (score 0):

Ich halte die Frage für schwer entscheidbar, da [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bergen) diese Bedeutung aber als erste nennt (übrigens unverändert zu [Grimm](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=B04217)), glaube ich nicht an eine Bedeutungsverschiebung.

Genau wie in

> Das Wrack barg manche Überraschung

nur von einem versteckten Enthalten die Rede ist (dem entspricht auch die wohl häufiger gebrauchte Verwendung im übertragenen Sinn) kann bergen im Sinne einer Tätigkeit als "einer schwer zugänglichen Person/Sache habhaft werden" bedeuten. Was im Anschluss damit passiert, im Fall einer verletzten Person also vielleicht die Behandlung durch einen Notarzt, ist zwar naheliegend, aber nicht augenfällig im Wort enthalten.

Neuere Treffer der [DWDS.Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=korpus21&q=bergen) geben auch keine weitere Einsicht: zumeist ist die übertragene Bedeutung gemeint, und bei Gegenständen ist die Unterscheidung noch schwieriger. Von daher tendiere ich zur Bedeutungsabweichung in der Fachsprache.